# How to find all possible ways to divide a string into n slices without recursion?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I need to write a function that receives a string and the number of groups, and then returns all the possible slicing options.

i.e. for `func('hello', 3)`:

```
[['h', 'e', 'llo'], ['h', 'el', 'lo'], ['h', 'ell', 'o'], ['he', 'll', 'o'], ['he', 'l', 'lo'], ['hel', 'l', 'o']]
```

How can I do this without using recursion? This is supposed to be possible only using loops and lists.

This is similar to a "divide balls into bins" problem, but in this case it's different because the order of objects never changes, just the slicing.

This is the code I currently have:

```
def divide_into_two(word):
    list_of_divs = []
    for i in range(1, len(word)):
        list_of_divs.append([word[0:i], word[i:len(word)]])

    return list_of_divs
```

It only divides a word into two groups. I figured we need some kind of inner loop to keep dividing it in case it's more groups, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Construct all tuples of positive numbers that sum up to `N = len(your_str)`. No doubt this has already been solved.

Comment: Interesting puzzle. To get help on stackoverflow, it is strongly recommended that you explain (by editing your question) what you have tried so far.

Comment: Tim, I'm sure this has been solved before. Constructing the tuples sounds more like a balls into bins question, but the order of objects must stay. For example ["e", "lmon"] is not a valid division for "lemon". @timgeb

Comment: If you have a recursive solution, you can mechanically transform it to an iterative solution by using a stack.

Comment: @kanyeeast The tuple approach does not shuffle the string. If you are constructing all tuples that sum up to `len(your_str)` then you get tuples like `(3, 1, 1)` which corresponds to `['hel', 'l', 'o']`. Or `(2, 2, 1)`, which corresponds to `['he', 'll', 'o']`.

Comment: FWIW, "has been solved before" is not a useful perspective when learning. If you only try to solve problems that have never been solved before, you will not be able to! ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `itertools.combinations` to pick indices of where to cut the string:

```
from itertools import combinations

def func(s, n):
    return [[s[i:j] for i, j in zip([None, *cuts], [*cuts, None])]
            for cuts in combinations(range(1, len(s)), n-1)]
```

Result of `func('hello', 3)`:

```
[['h', 'e', 'llo'], ['h', 'el', 'lo'], ['h', 'ell', 'o'], ['he', 'l', 'lo'], ['he', 'll', 'o'], ['hel', 'l', 'o']]
```

An alternative solution, starting with all single-slice divisions (i.e., just the whole string), then computing two-slice divisions, then three-slice divisions, etc. Done by always splitting the last slice into two, in all ways that allow the desired remaining number of splits:

```
def func(s, n):
    divs = [[s]]
    for i in range(n-1):
        divs = [[*keep, last[:j], last[j:]]
                for *keep, last in divs
                for j in range(1, len(last)-n+i+2)]
    return divs
```

Comment: Yeah I just forgot about these division. Thank you very much. Do you think it's possible to make a function like "combinations" in simple Python?

Comment: @kanyeeast Nothing is simpler Python than using the existing function :-). There's a possible implementation in [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), though that might be more general than necessary here. If I had to do it without itertools, I'd probably write a little recursive function.

Comment: @kanyeeast Added a second solution now, iterative instead of recursive because recursive would've bored me :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [more itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

```
from more_itertools import partitions

def divide_into_parts(word, parts):
    result = []
    for p in partitions(word):
        if len(p) == parts:
            result.append([''.join(s) for s in p])
    return result
```

Result

```
divide_into_parts('hello', 3)

[['h', 'e', 'llo'],
 ['h', 'el', 'lo'],
 ['h', 'ell', 'o'],
 ['he', 'l', 'lo'],
 ['he', 'll', 'o'],
 ['hel', 'l', 'o']]
```

Comment: Generating all partitions only to throw most away is not very efficient. It is better to think in terms of combinations of possible slice positions, using just `itertools`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from itertools import combinations

def slicings(s, g):
    for c in combinations(range(1, len(s)), g - 1):
        yield [s[start:end] for start, end in zip((0,) + c, c + (len(s),))]
```

You can now do whatever you want with you generator of slicings:

```
for slicing in slicings('hello', 3):
    print(slicing)
```

```
['h', 'e', 'llo']
['h', 'el', 'lo']
['h', 'ell', 'o']
['he', 'l', 'lo']
['he', 'll', 'o']
['hel', 'l', 'o']
```

In these cases, it's better to generate things as you need them (use `yield` instead of `return`) because there could be an exponential number of results depending on your specific case.